# How To Get Elapsed Time Getting REST GET request in async / await with httpclient in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

When I call the method DoRestCall below with Task.Wait, the elapsed time shows basically 0 (OK, it shows 3ms). I get that it is because of the async/await pattern.  I want to get the actual time it took to complete the rest call. I can't figure out a way to get inside HttpClient to figure that out.

```
public static async Task DoRestCall()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://http://myrest.com");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{x.Length} {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you only start the stopwatch AFTER the request? You are timing just the ReadAsString portion. async isn't the problem here, just your placement of the stopwatch.

Answer (score 5):

Others way to view `Elapsed Time` of HttpClient

1.Change [Log Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=aspnetcore-2.1)  to `Information` or `Trace`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      //"System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.LogicalHandler[100]
  Start processing HTTP request GET https://api.github.com/repos/aspnet/docs/branches

info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.ClientHandler[100]
  Sending HTTP request GET https://api.github.com/repos/aspnet/docs/branches

info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.ClientHandler[101]
  Received HTTP response after 682.9818ms - OK

info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.LogicalHandler[101]
  End processing HTTP request after 693.1094ms - OK
```

2.Creating a new [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#outgoing-request-middleware)

```
public class TimingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<TimingHandler> _logger;

    public TimingHandler(ILogger<TimingHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        _logger.LogInformation("Starting request");

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        _logger.LogInformation($"Finished request in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

        return response;
    }
}
```

For more details

- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers
- https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging

Answer (score 3):

You should move the stopwatch to include your `.GetAsync` call also.

```
public static async Task DoRestCall()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string responseBody = String.Empty;
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://http://myrest.com");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {        
        responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    sw.Stop();    
    Console.WriteLine($"{responseBody.Length} {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```